# Can I use my Linux-PC/Laptop as a Bluetooth headset for my mobile phone?

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth, headset

The same question exist for windows but NOT for linux.

Is it possible to use my linux-laptop (*which has connected a microphone and a speaker per Sound card*) over bluetooth as a headset for my mobile phone?

Is there any way do realise this with **BlueZ** (*bluetooth stack under linux*)?

I DON'T want to use my bluetooth headset with my PC.

I want to use my laptop/pc as headset per bluetooth for my mobile phone.

I use GNU/Linux Debian unstable.

Thanks for any infos!

Comment: Check out [this q/a on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/109533) for something other than HFP.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [HFP for Linux](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

HFP doesn't supported for modern version of linux anymore , unfortunately you can't

Comment: Do you have a source reference for this claim?

Comment: of course , but then I lose so many time, just wanna alert everyone who will googling about this topic : You can't use hfp on modern computer , if you can , i need a proof!

Comment: some guy on IRC send me this link, but even this doesn't work https://aurabindo.in/my-computer-is-my-bluetooth-headset/